# Unable to access my server with my domain name in http with a browser

Tags: networking, dns, http, nginx, https

I installed nginx on my server and want to access it with a browser using my domain name.

Basically i can do that using my server IP http://41.111.142.74/

Now trying to do that with my domain name which i bought from godaddy and pointed to my server's ip.

If i use some software utils like Postman, i'm able to get it. Works perfectly.
If i use a web browser i always get redirected (307) to the same url but in HTTPS.

My server is hosted in a Huawei infrastructure and i don't know much about how it's working behind there. But when i try to access the certificate details in Mozilla Firefox, it gives me informations about a FortiWeb Certificate.

I've googled about that thing, and found out it was a Web Application Firewall, any idea why it works with Postman and not with browsers ? and why it works with IP Access and not with Domain Name Access ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://41.111.142.74 (http version) returns "not found" while https://41.111.142.74  (https version) presents the security issue. Provide the domain name and one can see if it resolves to the correct IP; if it does it may be an issue with the server. It's also helpful if you post details about the server. Is it an unmanaged VPS? If the domain resolves to your IP, then it can be something with nginx configuration.

Comment: Yeah there was an issue with the server as well, they changed their certificate (FortiWeb) by an authenticated certificate i provided them, and now accessing the server in HTTPS only (y) and works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i ended by getting an SSL certificate and called them, they changed the FortWeb Certificate by my certificate and now i'm accessing the app in HTTPS